# Heapsize: already exceed the limit but still running?

Tags: apex, heapsizelimit

I am a bit confused on how can I handle heapsize to avoid getting a system exception.

Based on the below scenario, if I run following script

```
List<Attachment> attLST = new List<Attachment>();
Integer count = 0;
for (Attachment a: [SELECT Id,
                    Body,
                    BodyLength,
                    Name,
                    Description,
                    ParentId
                    FROM Attachment]) {
    count++;
    Attachment att = a.clone();
    att.Name = 'Cloned-' + att.Name;
    attLST.add(att);
    System.debug('Count: ' + count + ', Body Length: ' + a.BodyLength + ' - ' + a.Name);
    System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
    System.debug(Limits.getLimitHeapSize());
}
```

the logs looks like this, breaking in 111 from 140 in total.

[image: Salesforce heapsize limits]

The first row of the loop shows me:

[image: heapsize first record]

My question is: if the heapsize is 6000000, why it doesnt break on the first record? considering that at that moment the heapsize at that moment based in my logs is already a little bit over 11 times the limit? why it breaks when it has loop 110 times and the heapsize is already 20 times the limit?

Comment: Does this help you https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/184387/4517

Comment: @manjit5190 Actually not really, despite been the same topic that answer doesnt explain why the heapsize on the first loop is over the limit and why the exception doesnt happen there